# How to import a function or variable from the sibling directory of Django project?

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

I want to import some functions a constants variables from 5 levels upper of the current app of Django application.

My problem is that the package that I want to import from, is outside of the Django application, so Django isn't aware of it.

**project structure**:

```
├── lawcrawler
│   ├── get_all_amended_laws_urls.py # import a function from this file
│   ├── lawcrawler
│   │   └── spiders
│   │       └── settings.py # import variables from this file
│   │
├── project
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── laws
│   │       ├── management
│   │           ├── commands
│   │               ├── add_list_of_amended_laws.py # import function and variables to this file
│   ├── manage.py
```

As per [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), two or more leading dots indicate a relative import to the parent(s) of the current package, one level per dot after the first. So, I **tried relative import** like this:

```
from .......lawcrawler.lawcrawler.spiders.settings import SPARQL_ENDPOINT, AMENDED_URL_FILE_PATH, get_law_amendment_query
```

and this:

```
from .....lawcrawler import get_all_amended_urls
```

but **got this error**:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How to import the functions and variables or solve this issue?

Comment: Could you try just `lawcrawler import ....`

Comment: python it self search first local project to global project

Comment: Thanks @JavohirElmurodov, I have tried `from lawcrawler.get_all_amended_laws_urls import get_all_amended_urls`, but it doesn't work also.
When we import like so, the python looks to the root directory of Django where `manage.py` lives, so it doesn't search outside of the `project directory`.